# PHP get only one section of the html code

Tags: php, html

I have documentation on my project site on codeplex, and i want to create a PHP code to embed it to my site. and
[this is the part of code i want to get from the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixMyv.png)
If you could help me it would be great.

This is the code i want to extract from https://mxspli.codeplex.com/documentation:

```
<div id="WikiContent" class="WikiContent">

<div class="wikidoc">
<h1><img src="https://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download?ProjectName=mxspli&amp;DownloadId=1564842&amp;Build=21031" alt="" width="101" height="23">&nbsp;Documentation</h1>
<p>Welcome to MXSPLI Documentation</p>
<p>Here you can learn how to use MXSPLI, and how to make libraries for it.</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://mxspli.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tutorials">Tutorials</a> </li><li><a href="https://mxspli.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Released%20Libraries">Released Libraries</a>
</li><li><a href="https://mxspli.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Main%20Functions">Main Functions</a>
</li></ul>
</div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strpos will find the position of the string

```
$string = file_get_contents('https://mxspli.codeplex.com/documentation');
$pos = strpos($string,'<div id="WikiContent" class="WikiContent">');
$pos2 = strpos($string, "<div></div>", $pos);
$newstring = substr($string, $pos, ($pos2-$pos));
Echo $newstring;
```

Edit: I just noticed you wanted the html tags? If you don't want the tags check my first version of this answer.
EDIT2: sorry it didn't work when I tested it, but now it does.
...

Comment: Thank you for posting this.

Comment: Here we go again...  [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/797495)

Comment: @PedroLobito Sorry?? Where is the regex??

Comment: @PedroLobito Strpos is not regex, read the manual! http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Ops...my bad @Andreas! Can you make an edit so I can retract my vote? tks and sry.

Comment: @Andreas done, 1+ for `strpos`! altought, the correct way to do this is with an html parser like `DOMDocument` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DOMDocument` in PHP.

```
<?php
$pageHtml = file_get_contents('https://mxspli.codeplex.com/documentation');
$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHtml($pageHtml);

/* Write out the HTML snippet */
echo $document->saveHTML($document->getElementById('WikiContent'));
```

Comment: I've tested your code and it doesn't work, I get 
`Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /home/...` without any further data.

Comment: @PedroLobito You are using an outdated version of PHP.  This will work with PHP 5.3.6 or greater.